# Removing first value after series of NaN of dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

My dataframe called `ozon` with one column `O3` is filled with hundreds of series with `NaN` values. In itself it's not a problem, however for some reason every first value after these series is overshooting, by a lot. For example:

```
                       O3
Datetime                  
2019-10-17 21:30:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:35:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:40:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:45:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:50:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:55:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:00:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:05:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:10:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:15:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:20:00  55.08
2019-10-17 22:25:00  36.25
2019-10-17 22:30:00  36.31
2019-10-17 22:35:00  36.46
2019-10-17 22:40:00  36.51
2019-10-17 22:45:00  36.58
2019-10-17 22:50:00  36.75
2019-10-17 22:55:00  36.71
2019-10-17 23:00:00  36.83
2019-10-17 23:05:00  36.81
```

In the image below you can see it as well, perhaps more clearly.

[image]

So I want to remove the first "real" value after every series of NaN values. So my desired outcome in the provided example would be:

```
                       O3
Datetime                  
2019-10-17 21:30:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:35:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:40:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:45:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:50:00    NaN
2019-10-17 21:55:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:00:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:05:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:10:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:15:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:20:00    NaN
2019-10-17 22:25:00  36.25
2019-10-17 22:30:00  36.31
2019-10-17 22:35:00  36.46
2019-10-17 22:40:00  36.51
2019-10-17 22:45:00  36.58
2019-10-17 22:50:00  36.75
2019-10-17 22:55:00  36.71
2019-10-17 23:00:00  36.83
2019-10-17 23:05:00  36.81
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shift to check prv row and isnull to check NaN is
what you need as below:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',')
print(df)

df['O3'] = np.where(df['O3'].shift(1).isnull(), np.nan, df['O3'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Datetime                         O3
0           2019-10-17 21:30:00    NaN
1           2019-10-17 21:35:00    NaN
2           2019-10-17 21:40:00    NaN
3           2019-10-17 21:45:00    NaN
4           2019-10-17 21:50:00    NaN
5           2019-10-17 21:55:00    NaN
6           2019-10-17 22:00:00    NaN
7           2019-10-17 22:05:00    NaN
8           2019-10-17 22:10:00    NaN
9           2019-10-17 22:15:00    NaN
10          2019-10-17 22:20:00  55.08
11          2019-10-17 22:25:00  36.25
12          2019-10-17 22:30:00  36.31
13          2019-10-17 22:35:00  36.46
14          2019-10-17 22:40:00  36.51
15          2019-10-17 22:45:00  36.58
16          2019-10-17 22:50:00  36.75
17          2019-10-17 22:55:00  36.71
18          2019-10-17 23:00:00  36.83
19          2019-10-17 23:05:00  36.81
   Datetime                         O3
0           2019-10-17 21:30:00    NaN
1           2019-10-17 21:35:00    NaN
2           2019-10-17 21:40:00    NaN
3           2019-10-17 21:45:00    NaN
4           2019-10-17 21:50:00    NaN
5           2019-10-17 21:55:00    NaN
6           2019-10-17 22:00:00    NaN
7           2019-10-17 22:05:00    NaN
8           2019-10-17 22:10:00    NaN
9           2019-10-17 22:15:00    NaN
10          2019-10-17 22:20:00    NaN
11          2019-10-17 22:25:00  36.25
12          2019-10-17 22:30:00  36.31
13          2019-10-17 22:35:00  36.46
14          2019-10-17 22:40:00  36.51
15          2019-10-17 22:45:00  36.58
16          2019-10-17 22:50:00  36.75
17          2019-10-17 22:55:00  36.71
18          2019-10-17 23:00:00  36.83
19          2019-10-17 23:05:00  36.81
```

Comment: Yess! This worked really well! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ive used 0's instead of Nans but the same rule applies, in my solution there's a few steps you need to take to be able to cleanse your data set

firstly get all the indexes of NaN (0 in this case)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'03': [1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 5, 7]})
print(df)
idxs = df.index[df['03'] == 0].tolist()
print(idxs)
```

Then get all the indexes where the difference is not 1 and add the last element of the index array (as this will not be picked up)

```
diff_i = [i for i, j in zip(idxs[:-1], idxs[1:]) if j-i!=1]
diff_i.append(idxs[-1])
print(diff_i)
```

Then loop through and reassign all values like so

```
for i in diff_i:
    df.at[i+1, '03'] = 0

print(df)
```

which will go from a dataframe of

```
    03
0    1
1    2
2    4
3    3
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    2
8    5
9    3
10   5
11   0
12   0
13   0
14   1
15   4
16   5
17   6
18   0
19   0
20   5
21   7
```

to a dataframe of

```
    03
0    1
1    2
2    4
3    3
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    5
9    3
10   5
11   0
12   0
13   0
14   0
15   4
16   5
17   6
18   0
19   0
20   0
21   7
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work, as the idxs list is still empty after: idxs = df.index[df['03'] == 'NaN'].tolist()

Comment: you might have to use ```idxs = df.index[df['03'] == np.nan].tolist() ```